# Batman Cartoon Movie featuring Satellite-based Blast

Tags: story-identification, dc, movie, batman, cartoon

About 7-8 years ago,  I watched a Batman cartoon movie on Cartoon Network in which Joker used an energy blast originating from a satellite. Before each blast, a light beam was projected to target. Batman always escaped the blast due to this light beam indicator from the satellite. Robin was also a character in this movie.

Can you please identify the movie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond%3a_Return_of_the_Joker) (also known as Batman of the Future: Return of the Joker in Europe and Australia) is a 2000 direct-to-video animated film.

> ... Back in the Batcave, Terry deduces that Tim must be working with the Joker when he discovers that the high-tech equipment the Joker have been stealing **can be combined to form a machine that take control of any satellite**, thus explaining what happened on the yacht.

Comment: Such a good movie...